# ReadLine() reads only once

Tags: c#

```
    private void btnServer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TcpListener listen = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1237);
        listen.Start();
        client = listen.AcceptTcpClient();
        txtContent.Text = "Connected" + "\n";
        s = client.Client;
        str = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
        stw = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
        stw.AutoFlush = true;

        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        //backgroundWorker2.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;


    }

    private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        client.Close();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        while (client.Connected)
        {
            try
            {
                while ((receive = str.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    txtContent.AppendText(receive + "\n");
                    receive = "";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want the program to listen to requests, connect with the client and receive all the data sent by the client.
Problems I face:

- My Server gets stuck when the client takes more than 2 sec to connect
- Readline() reads only the first line of the text that is sent by the device
- I'm quite unaware of how to close the connection as the client.Close() pops up an exception.

I would love to solve these problems. Any explanation regarding these issues would also be appreciated.

Comment: Aside from anything else, it looks like you're trying to modify the UI on a background thread - you're not meant to do that. Next, we don't know what the client is doing...

Comment: Also, don't use `StreamReader` (and I wouldn't use `StreamWriter` either) with network streams. And, given that you're dealing with naturaly asynchronous APIs, why use a background worker? The subtle issues you have with your networking code are deadly for production code, but are not going to tank your demo - but really, doing networking in such a guessing manner isn't a good idea.

Comment: The client sends a list of strings( a shopping list line by line) and I have to receive it from an application - a simple set of strings line by line. I  wanted to display the strings as the readline() always returned null.

Comment: Uhmm, tell me the best place to start learning better, because it is going in over my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to call AcceptTcpClient from your background worker, so your UI thread is not stuck while you are waiting for the client to connect.

You should only call GetStream() once; save the result as a Stream object and you can get both the reader and writer from it.

Your background worker should not call AppendText directly; it should call ReportProgress(0, text).  You can't update the UI from a background thread.
The method that creates the background worker should add an event handler to the background worker's ReportProgress event that updates the text.  The event will be run on the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks, got results for most of my issues. Could you please explain the GetStream() part of it ??

Comment: You want to do something like: Stream socketStream = client.GetStream(); str = new StreamReader(socketStream);
        stw = new StreamWriter(socketStream);  You don't want to call GetStream() more than once on the same socket

Comment: But it still reads only the first line from the stream.It's like I'm receiving data(shopping list) from an android application, but readLine() returns null after the first line.

Comment: Problem Solved. I'd a minor glitch and l looked beyond a logical error. Thanks everyone :)